# SELECT rows but give preference to non-NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table A as follows:

```
uid      | productid | price 
1        | 1         | 15    
2        | 1         | 20    
1        | 2         | 24    
NULL     | 1         | 90    
NULL     | 2         | 49
```

I need an SQL query that will return for a a specific uid, productid the price, but if this uid, productid pair does not exist will return the price for uid NULL and same productid.

For the above example if I ask the price of uid=1 and productid=1 I need the 1st row returned (and not the 4th).
If I ask the price of uid=2 and productid=2 I need the last row returned this time since there is no (2,2) pair for uid and productid.

I hope it is clear...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if there are multiple matching `(uid, productid)` pairs?  Or is that guaranteed never to happen?

Comment: This is guaranteed not to happen, assume the pair is PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both: `where uid=2 or uid is null`. And then take the first record ordered by not null values first.

```
Select price
from TableName
where productid=2
and (uid=2 or uid is null)
order by uid is null
limit 1
```